# multiple rows with different column headers and data under the same column header in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to display the data as follows. It has  different header rows under the same main header. And 1 evid can have any number of docref's . And towards the end there is no main column header only sub column headers are there .Please help.(i am using sql server 2012)

```
   EVID Basis   Period  Evidence   AssignedTo  EVEditors  FileName
   1234 CAI     2011    Load       Jack      jack,jill  caidoc.txt  

                        DocRef  Specific      LastUser    DocType     DocTitle     DocID 
                         12       report      jack        case         abc         111111

                                  fileName    url        details  
                                   xyz        sometext    sometext

                                   linkText     Notes
                                   some text      some text

                        DocRef  Specific      LastUser    DocType     DocTitle     DocID  
                          13      report2     jill       case2         abc         22222

                                   fileName    url        details  
                                    xyz        sometext    sometext

                                   linkText     Notes
                                   some text      some text
```

Comment: Can you format your sample data better? I have no clue what that is supposed to look like (note you can use `<pre>` tags)

Comment: which is your programming language? do you use any grid object? why is all workload on tsql side? can UI assist in someway?

Comment: do you expect this `DocRef Specific LastUser DocType DocTitle DocID`, this `fileName url details`, and this `linkText Notes` sub-headers returned as rows inside the ordered recorset output?

Comment: @Luis Siquot: this is for a vendor software where we cannot do a front end programming, the software will just display the sql resultset in a table . Yes ,all subheaders must be returned as the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Report building like this is better done using tools for report building (SSRS), if hell-bent on formatting in SQL you can do it (painfully) using `UNION` and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EVID) RowRank
             FROM YourTable)
    SELECT 'EVID', 'Basis',  'Period',  'Evidence',   'AssignedTo',  'EVEditors',  'FileName'
    UNION 
    SELECT EVID, Basis,   Period,  Evidence,   AssignedTo,  EVEditors,  FileName
    FROM cte
    WHERE RowRank = 1
    UNION
    SELECT '','','','DocRef','Specific', 'LastUser', 'DocType',  'DocTitle', 'DocID'
    UNION
    SELECT  DocRef, Specific, LastUser, DocType, DocTitle, DocID 
    FROM cte
    WHERE RowRank = 1
    ......
```

`CAST` everything that's not already to `VARCHAR(50)`
`UNION` should be `UNION` + `ALL` just can't post those words together due to firewall restriction.

You could use a loop to build the repeating portion of the statement, but again, this is solving a problem in SQL that doesn't need to be solved in SQL.

Comment: Why do this, it is a report?  Result sets should be just data.  Also,  This would show all the headers (n) rows followed by all the details (m).  It should be a joined result set (n x m) which is pretty printed.

Comment: I agree, best done outside of SQL as I mentioned. Perhaps I should emphasize that more.

Comment: @craftydba: it is not a report , we have a application which uses sql query and displays it on front end as we send.

Comment: @Goat Co : i was doing it by union , but i am not able to control the order in which the headers and details are appearing.

Comment: Again, if a business user came to me with this issue, I would say go write a report.

Comment: When you start mixing in header text with header rows and detail text with detail rows, you end up with a real mess.  Only suggestion I can give you is to write a cursor that traverses the header and detail rows in the right order.  Why use fields at all?  Just output a result set as two fields (line_no & line_text).  Mix text and data as you want.  The line_no tells the the order of the data.   GOOD LUCK!

Comment: If you want to continue doing this with `UNION` you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to control the order, see updated answer.  Still agree with @CRAFTYDBA that this is not a good approach for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You do understand that a query only returns rows.  While you can write complex TSQL to blank out fields, I would not suggest it.  Therefore, EVID information will repeated for both DocRef 12 and DocRef 13.

```
EVID ...  DocRef

1234 ...  12 
1234 ...  13
```

What you are showing here is a report.  You will need SSRS or some report writer to pretty print the data by only showing the header row (parent) once.  Then two child rows.

Here is a quick sample database to play with.

```
 -- Sample table 1
 create table #header
 (
    evid int,
    basis varchar(3),
    period int,
    evidence varchar(16),
    assigned_to varchar(32),
    editors varchar(32),
    file_names varchar(32)
);

-- Add data 2 table 1
insert into #header values
(1234, 'CAI', 2011, 'Load', 'Jack', 'jack,jill', 'caidoc.txt');

-- Add data 2 table 1
insert into #header values
(5678, 'ABC', 2013, 'Load', 'Johnny', 'johnny,appleseed', 'apples.txt');


 -- Sample table 2
 create table #detail
 (
    evid int,
    docref int,
    specific varchar(16),
    last_user varchar(32),
    doc_type varchar(32),
    doc_title varchar(32),
    doc_id int,
    file_names varchar(32),
    url varchar(32),
    details varchar(32),
    link_text varchar(64),
    notes varchar(128)
);

-- Add data 2 table 2
insert into #detail values
(1234, 12, 'report', 'jack', 'case', 'abc', 111111, 'xyz', 'url1', 'detail1', 'link1', 'notes1');

-- Add data 2 table 2
insert into #detail values
(1234, 13, 'report', 'jill', 'case', 'abc', 222222, 'xyz', 'url1', 'detail1', 'link1', 'notes1');


-- Joining the parent to the child.
select * from #header as h left join #detail as d on h.evid = d.evid
```

The join gives the following result.  Use a report writer to pretty up the output.

[image]
Good luck.